# Twitter embedded timeline inside a polymer element

Tags: javascript, twitter, polymer

I'm trying to implement twitter embedded timeline inside a polymer element. But there's a problem: twitter's widgets.js script cannot get the anchor element,which is inside the shadow dom. To solve this issue i overwrite some methods of document element and after widgets.js finished executing i restore standart methods of document. It works,but seems very unsafe.Could somebody have a better solution?

Comment: Why not just use ajax to fetch the feeds, then parse and visualize however you want?

Answer (score 0):

After trying similar tricks to yours, I found out that answer is trivial!

Looking into Twitter docs (https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization), I found out you can tell it to look for dynamically created widgets, at any given point, traversing down from a given node.

This means you simply need to plug it in on Polymer ready:

```
...
  <template>

    <a class="twitter-timeline" height="500" href="https://twitter.com/joaomgvieira">Tweets by joaomgvieira</a>

  </template>

  <script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
      t._e.push(f);
    };

    return t;
  }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      ready: function () {
        twttr.ready(function () {
          twttr.widgets.load(this);
        }.bind(this));
      }

    });
  </script>
...
```

To make it reusable I created https://github.com/joaovieira/twitter-widgets .

That should easily do the trick, so you can use your embeds as you would before.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a Polymer component with the widget.js library from Twitter: https://github.com/LasaleFamine/polymer-twitter-timeline

I'm using another library of mine for the loading of the library: https://github.com/LasaleFamine/polymer-lib-loader

You can easily check the source code of both.

I'm using this element in some of my projects and it's working pretty good.
I hope could be useful and also PRs are welcome!